Did the Idolatrous Women of Ezekiel's Time Willfully Place Their Idol in the More Egregious Location in Order to Repudiate God?
In Ezekiel 8, the prophet is brought to the Temple in a vision and shown a series of abominations that explain why the Temple is to be destroyed.
Firstly, he is brought to the entrance of the courtyard; he peers through a hole in the wall of the Azara (that he enlarges) and sees the entrance of a chamber and enters and sees every form of creeping thing and detestable animal - idols - engraved on the wall of that chamber (see Metzudot Dovid). Seventy Men and Yazniyahu are offering incense there. He is told that he would be shocked if he knew what these men were doing in the dark in their own chambers (see Metzudos Dovid). Then he is informed that he will see "greater abominations."
He is then taken to the gate of the Heichal (see Metzudos) and shown that inside of the Chamber of the Knives (per Rashi) women are heating an idol from the inside called Tammuz, which has lead eyes, thereby causing the idol to 'weep,' - this means that it wants more sacrifices (see Metzudos and Rashi). Once again, he is told that he will see something worse.
Why is Tammuz the greater abomination?
The easy answer is that it's all about proximity ("where"). Tammuz was found deeper within the Temple complex and thus it is the more egregious crime.
But it doesn't sound here like proximity alone creates the more egregious crime. And so if Tamuz is worse for independent reasons - Tammuz was perfidious in that it duped others ... The seventy + one men were merely sinning on their own- this begs the question: how did the more shocking crime end up in the more shocking place? Did the women willfully place the more heinous act in a location which expressed more rebelliousness?

The women were "weeping for Tammuz", a fertility god who would go to the underworld every year, causing the summers to become too hot to grow crops.

I suspect it was a transgression of appetite rather than a transgression of angering God (https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avodah_Zarah.26b.4?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi). So no, IMO they didn't put Tammuz there because it was the worse idolatrous act but rather because it better satiated their need for glorifying Tammuz.

@ Harel13. Thx. The irony then is that they chose the more choice location -  closer to God - for their idol!

Several of the commentators on that verse (Abarbanel, Radak, Malbim) state that "the Tammuz" here is a form of the Molech worship of child sacrifice. Thus, as bad as it was for the elders to be worshipping creeping things and whatnot, this was indeed worse.
